# CPU to run with GTX 950

Tags: gaming, processor

I am planning to buy computer with main target for games. I was looking through fat lists of CPU, GPU and other computer parts and I am a bit confused for now.

The graphic card I have choosen is probably GeForce GTX 950. Then I would like to build 8 GB of RAM memory and HDD hard disk. What I am not sure is CPU and motherboard.

I was thinking about:

1. Intel i5 4460
2. Intel i5 4690
3. AMD FX-8300
4. AMD FX-8350
5. some other recommendations...

Please if you may suggest me something I would be thankful.
If someone know what motherboard will be good for this set, feel free to share.

---

**Edit**

The computer would be for gaming as I wrote. Budget would be around 650 euro.

Of course there must be a card which is going to allow me access internet. I do not think that sound card is required for me as well as other extensions. I need motherboard (not specified), GPU, CPU, internet card, memory and hard disk, power and cooler system. I think that would be complete computer. Am I missing something ? The main part of computer will be CPU and GPU as I know, so I am concentrated on those parts now. I would like to have 8GB of fast memory as I heard it is important.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What are you using this computer for? What is your budget? Are you using any other expansion cards (e.g. sound card, RAID card, NIC, etc.)?

Comment: What criteria would make you choose this or that CPU? Typically you'd take the fastest CPU that you can afford on your budget, unless you pick a slower CPU because it uses less power. The motherboard is where you have a lot of choices.

Comment: Which country do you need shipping to?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this computer purely for gaming, the CPU and motherboard doesn't matter as much as the GPU. All you need is a current generation CPU with a compatible motherboard and you should spend more on the GPU. Games will run basically the same on the 4 CPU's you listed, so my recommendation would be to get the cheaper one you can find. For the Intel CPU's I would recommend a H97 or a Z97 chipset motherboard, so just buy one from a reputable brand and reviews and is budget friendly. For the AMD CPU's I would recommend a AM3+ socket motherboard, just get a cheap one from a reputable brand and reviews.